# check for permutation in bash

Tags: bash, shell, unix, sh

I have a script wherein you have to input a string with a length greater then or equal to 1 and less then 26.

If that's not the case I want to return an error. But that's the part I have figured out

```
lengthAlphabetInput=${#1}

if [ $lengthAlphabetInput -lt 1 ] || [ $lengthAlphabetInput -gt 26 ]
then
echo "error: key needs to be between 1 and 26 characters"
exit 1
fi
```

Other than that I would like to check if the input the user gave is a permutation of (a part of) the alphabet.

> For example if the user inputs "abc" I want to return an error "abc is
>   not a permutation of the alphabet"
>
> if the user inputs "xxxgsdnoip" I again want to return the same error
>   because I don't want the user to use the same letter more than once.
>
> But the input "xyz" or "jhcwslaedmviotrgzxkbynpuqf" would be correct
>   because these are permutations of the alphabet. (x instead of a, y
>   instead of b and z instead of c).

Can anyone help me transform this idea into code?

Comment: Why is "xyz" acceptable but "abc" is not?

Comment: Show us what you have tried and where you are stuck. Explain which tools you would use. Try something. Show us your effort.

Comment: A permutation of the alphabet would be any string exactly 26 letters long, containing each letter of the alphabet exactly once, where the order of the letters is unimportant.

Comment: Do this: `filter the characters with the regex `[a-z]`, split each character in one line, sort, uniq, count lines (wc -l)`. Do it yourself, try to really learn.

Answer (score 1):

I realized that this is a question raised by a student, so I did not write down a detailed answer, since the experience of reading manual and figuring it out yourself will really help you learn how to use bash (actually the GNU/BSD core utilities), as said by @binaryzebra. What you should do is:

1. Learn to read manual in bash, with command `man`, such as `man sort` for the manual of `sort` utility. Hit Up/Down arrow key or PageUp/PageDown key to scroll; hit `q` to exit. Reading manual is your first step into Unix world. Sure you can skip this and find all the information from Google, but learning to read manual will do you more good in the long run.
2. Read the manual of `sed` and learn substitution with regular expression. The manual is a little too long for a newcomer, but luckily you do not need to read it all; just scan the manual and find the part about substitution; read the examples as well, if there is any. Practice with some test file. Now you know how to check whether input contains only letters (instead of whitespace, symbols, etc.), as well as how to split each character in its own line.
3. Read the manual of `uniq`. It has a much shorter manual; reading the whole manual won't take long.
4. Now learn the pipeline feature in bash. I cannot find a short and focused manual entry, so you may as well just read [the online manual from GNU](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pipelines.html). With the help of pipeline, you can combine `sed` and `uniq` to detect duplicated characters.
5. By "permutation", it seems that you do not want the characters in their original order. If so, read the manual of the `sort` utility and think how it can help you.
6. You do not seem to care about whether all 26 letters are there. If this is the case, you probably do not need the `wc` (word count) utility, unless you require the subset of letters be continuous (such as "cdefg" instead of "cdhjk").

That's all the hints; good luck with your homework.

Comment: Thanks alot for your answer! That's exactly what I did. I tried to come up with my very own answer that's how I learn most (of course I also got some inspiration from the people that helped). This is what I came up with `lengthAlphabetInput=${#1} Input1=$1
Alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
AlphabetAdaptedInput=$(echo "$Alphabet" | cut -c1-"$lengthAlphabetInput")
if [ $Input1 == $AlphabetAdaptedInput ]
then
echo "fout: sleutel is geen permutatie van het alfabet"
exit 2
fi   if echo "$1" | grep -q '\([[:alpha:]]\).*\1'
then
echo "fout: sleutel is geen permutatie van het alfabet"
exit 2
fi`

Comment: @Joey Comments are not decent place to write code blocks; you might want to paste them in [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) or something similar. :)

Comment: @Joey Good job! `grep` is actually one of the most heavily used utilities. It seems that the input is assumed to be letter-only?

Comment: Yes it is, in the complete script I write an error message if it isn't somewhere in the beginning

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$_=shift;

print "not ok:repeated: $1\n" if/(.).*\1/;  

my $i=0;
my @s= ( map { ord($_)-97 != $i++ ? ():($_)} split(''));
print "not ok:samePlace: @s\n" if @s;
```

usage:

```
$ perl ex.pl rty

$ perl ex.pl abc
not ok:samePlace: a b c

$ perl ex.pl ddss
not ok:repeated: d
```

Comment: Is it possible to not use perl? It is for school and I am supposed to do it in bash